# Node.js: Testing with VCR

Tags: javascript, node.js, vcr

Is there a [VCR](http://railscasts.com/episodes/291-testing-with-vcr?autoplay=true) testing system for node.js?

Answer (score 11):

Node nock, which is part of the [flatiron library/framework](http://flatironjs.org) has this feature, look [here](https://github.com/flatiron/nock#recording)

Comment: Nock is the real node-equivalent of VCR; VCR.js is specific only to browser(like) environments, since it records `XMLHttpRequest` events.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I use [node-replay](https://github.com/assaf/node-replay):

> ### Node Replay
>
> #### When API testing slows you down: record and replay HTTP responses like a boss
>
> Things that will ruin your day when tests make HTTP requests to other
> services:
>
> - That other service has the uptime of Twitter's API
> - Network late............ ncy
> - Being-rate limited and having to wait an hour for the
>   next test run
> - Same request returns different result each time
> - Everyone
>   else on the network is deep in BitTorrent terittory
>
> Things node-replay
> can do to make these problems go away:
>
> - Record API response once, replay as often as necessary
> - Stub HTTP
>   requests (TBD)
> - Replay different responses to same request (great for
>   testing error handling)
> - Not suck

Answer (score 4):

Update (2012-02-08): [VCR.js](https://github.com/elcuervo/vcr.js) was recently released.

Not that I know of.  It sounds like [@derwildemomo is working on one](http://twitter.com/#!/derwildemomo/status/126333721006702592), though.

If you find one, let me know and I'll be happy to add a link to it from VCR's readme.

Answer (score 4):

Update(2017-03-29):

VCR.js
https://github.com/elcuervo/vcr.js

Nock
https://github.com/node-nock/nock#recording

Sepia
https://github.com/linkedin/sepia

Yakbak
https://github.com/flickr/yakbak

Answer (score 0):

Guzzle a similar tool, but it's bundled with the PHP library: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/tests/Guzzle/Tests/Http/server.js